# Google automatic location dropdown list is not showing

Tags: php, forms, google-maps-api-3

I am working on website ...in which  when i click on the source location and destination location input  fields it  doesn't show the google automatic locations....thus , the input fields are fetching the result ..but the dropdown is not showing..

What should i do..?

My working link is below..you can see the link ,and figureout the issues:

My script is below:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<API KEY>&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
  function init() {
            var options = {
            componentRestrictions: {country: "au"}};
            var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
            var input2 = document.getElementById('locationTextField2');var input3 = document.getElementById('location1');
            var input4 = document.getElementById('location2');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
            var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2,options);
            var autocomplete3 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input3,options);
            var autocomplete4 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input4,options);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);


    </script>
```

Comment: [The posted code works for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dr6q7w69/).  Might be a problem with your key (check the javascript console).  If not, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will work :**

HTML input field for autosuggest.

```
<input placeholder="location" onFocus="init(this);">
```

JS Code.

```
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "in"},
    strictBounds:true
};

function init(input) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(place);
    });
}

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY&libraries=places" async defer></script>
```